# Javascript socket emitting from server then listening from client not working

Tags: javascript, express, sockets

I'm doing this code that emits from serverside and listens from clientside, The connection never ends until the client refresh or exits the page but that is not the case, the thing is that the code on clientside doesn't get execute and no error is showing on the logs.

ServerSide Code:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        console.log("New socket connection");

        

        socket.on('joinApp', ({msg, password}) =>{

            let username;
            let rooms;

            
            model.findOne({username: msg}, function(err, found){
                if(!err){
                    var checka = false;
                    if(found){
                        if(found.password === password){
                            user = userLogged(socket.id, msg, found.rooms);
                            username = getUserName(socket.id).username;
                            rooms = getUserName(socket.id).rooms;
                            console.log(msg + " Has entered the chat");
                            console.log(socket.id);
                            checka = true;
                        }else{
                            console.log("Incorrect password");
                        }
                    
                    
                    }else{
                        console.log("User not found");

                    }
                    io.to(socket.id).sockets.emit("checker", checka);
                }
            });

        
        


            socket.on('myRooms', () =>{
                let user = getUserName(socket.id);
                let username = user.username;
                let rooms = user.rooms;

                if(user.rooms.length === 0){
                    console.log(username + " You have no rooms");
                    socket.emit("yourRooms", {username, rooms});
                }else{


                }

            });









        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            console.log("Disconnected");


        });


        });
```

});

This is the code i have on my express js file, if you see here:

```
io.to(socket.id).emit("yourRooms", {username, rooms});
```

The line above is where the problem is, i am emitting the signal that i'm going to listen clientside but the client don't listen to it (Clientside code below):

```
let title = document.getElementById("title");
let rooms = document.getElementById("rooms");


    console.log(socket.id);

    socket.on("yourRooms", (username, rooms) => {


        if(rooms.length === 0){
            rooms.innerHTML = "You have no rooms";
        }

        title.innerHTML = user + "'s rooms";


    });
```

This part of the code will print the exact `socket.id` of the client so no problem here.

```
console.log(socket.id);
```

I'm not declaring another socket instance since that way it didn't work

I'm using this exact approach in another part of my code and it is working, it's in the file where I created my socket instance:

```
const socket = io();
```

I've been trying for hours, no error in the logs and the `socket.id` is correct when I console.log in the clientside script where I'm having problems, so I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: If all you're trying to do on the server is send a message back to the same client that just sent the server a message, then you can just do `socket.emit(...)` as `socket` should still have the same value as it did in the `socket.on('connect', ...)` unless you reassigned the `socket` variable and if you did that, then `socket.id` won't be valid either.  I'd suggest you show us a larger code context on the server so we can see this whole code block on the server.

Comment: I load  another ejs file with the jquery method .load() and i see that maybe the problem is in there since after that line of code executes i cannot emit somewhere else, so that might be the problem i guess?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't really participate in a question where it takes you 6 days to respond.  All mental context is completely gone and it's incredibly inefficient to try to get your head back into the context.

Comment: You would probably have to show the code for the larger context of what you're doing with this template loading for people to have any idea how to consider that as part of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are emitting an object in express

```
io.to(socket.id).emit("yourRooms", {username, rooms});
```

And you are listening for different arguments in client side

```
socket.on("yourRooms", (username, rooms) => {
```

Try changing it to

```
socket.on("yourRooms", ({username, rooms}) => {
```

Comment: I've done that method in the past but still is not listening to the socket.

Comment: Did you check if the socket connects or not? If not try passing custom host on the client side like demonstrated here: https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-api/index.html